# DOM Event has no 'target' property if handled as 'Object' - Atom says

Tags: javascript, typescript, atom-editor, dom-events

In the template:

```
<input (change)="changed($event)" ...
```

In the TypeScript file:

```
private changed(event: Object): void {
...event.target.value...
}
```

Atom shows me the following error:

> Property 'target' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Why?

If I remove `: Object`, everything works just great. Mentioning `: Object` there, isn't even necessary at all. I'm just wondering what could cause this error message..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of an event should be `Event` -- which is what contains the `target` property:

```
private changed(event: Event): void {
    // You can access `event.target` here.
    // If you want to access event.target.value you have to assert event.target as `HTMLInputElement` because not all event targets are input elements:
    var value = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
}
```